# Get user ID while login from the LoginController.php laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I want to get user id immediately after the user has logged in.
I have tried getting the user id using request but its not working. It prints the following error:

> "Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController::redirectTo(), 0 passed in C:\Users\owden\Documents\donation_system\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RedirectsUsers.php on line 15 and exactly 2 expected"

Below is my LoginController.php.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected function redirectTo(Request $request, $id)
    {
        if(Auth::user()->usertype == 'admin')
        {
            return 'dashboard';
        }
        elseif(Auth::user()->usertype == 'organization') {
            $user = User::find($id);
            return redirect ('/profile/{'.$id.'}');
        }else{
            return 'approval';
        }
    }
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

And the routes:

```
Route::get('/profile', 'ProfilesController@index')->name('profile.show');
Route::get('/profile/{user}/edit', 'ProfilesController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
Route::patch('/profile/{user}', 'ProfilesController@update')->name('profile.update');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to pass `$id` to `redirectTo()`; you have `Auth::user()`, so you can get the `id` from that:

```
protected function redirectTo()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if($user->usertype == 'admin')
    {
        return 'dashboard';
    } else if($user->usertype == 'organization') {
        return '/profile/'.$user->id.'/edit';
    } else {
        return 'approval';
    }
}
```

Summary of changes:

1. Removed `Request $request` and `$id` from `redirectTo()` function
2. Set `$user` to `Auth::user()` so you don't have to call it multiple times.
3. Removed query `User::find($id);` it's redundant if you already have `Auth::user()`
4. Adjusted return if `usertype == 'organization'`; All the other checks are returning a string, so it stands that this one should too.
5. Fixed URL being returned. `{'.$user->id.'}'` is just wrong. The `{}` are placeholders to signify a URL parameter in the routes file; don't actually include them. Also, you don't have a `GET` route for `/profile/{user}`, just one for `/profile/{user}/edit`, so use that.

As you can see, `Auth::user()` contains the user information, so you don't need to pass `$id`, and you don't need to query `User::find($id);`

Comment: Thanks, Now it can pick the user id but i am getting another error. "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: PATCH". Should i replace "get" with "patch"

Comment: You've got 2 different routes; `/profile/{user}/edit` and `/profile/{user}`; one is a `GET`, one is `PATCH`. You need to redirect to the `GET` one (as displayed in my answer), but you can keep the `PATCH` one as-is for any form submissions.